# how to skip the all testcase when setup_class raise exception

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

does any know how can I skip the testsuite if there is a exception occurs on setup_class? I have the code like following

```
import pytest
#@pytest.mark.skip(reason='skip if testsuite') #i can put skip here to skip all TestSuite
class TestSuite():
    @classmethod
    def setup_class(cls):
        try:
            raise Exception(f'can not find suitable strategy: {e}')
        except Exception as a:
            #I want to skip the testsuite for all testcase

    def test_func1(self):
        pass 
    def test_func2(self):
        pass 
    def test_func3(self):
        pass
```

Answer (score 0):

http://doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html

You could put this in your exception block:

```
pytest.skip("failed to complete setup")
```